# Reading data from a text file in Python according to the parameters provided

Tags: python, split, file-read

I have a text file something like this

```
Mqtt_allowed=true
Mqtt_host=192.168.0.1
Mqtt_port=2223
<=============>
cloud_allowed=true
cloud_host=m12.abc.com
cloud_port=1232
<=============>
local_storage=true
local_path=abcd
```

I needed to get each of the value w.r.t parameter provided by the user.
What i am doing right now is:

```
def search(param):
    try:
        with open('config.txt') as configuration:
            for line in configuration:
                if not line:
                    continue    
                function, f_input=line.split("=")
                if function == param:
                    result=f_input.split()
                    break
                else:
                    result="0"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found: ")
    return result

mqttIsAllowed=search("Mqtt_allowed")
print mqttIsAllowed
```

Now when i call only mqt stuff it is working fine but when i call cloud or anything after the "<==========>" separation it throws an error. Thanks

Comment: Please post the traceback of the error you're getting.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using that symbol string to separate? Why do you need to separate? Is a blank line not good enough either?

Comment: the reason is that.. i am making a text file for the non coders to write the credentials and that symbol just gives them the clearity and separation in the text file

Comment: Perhaps not super important but what error are you getting?

Comment: The error was NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined. but it is now working fine by the solution given by ForceBru below..

Comment: I am also getting the same error if the code is unable to find the param

Comment: See my post and it will explain why the answer I have provided solves your problem.

Comment: With respect to the exception issue you are having, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.13..

Comment: @HassanHaroon, try opening a nonexistent file and see what exception you'll get. This is the exception you want to catch in the `except` block.

Comment: @HassanHaroon The reason you cant catch that exception is because it doesn't exist in 2.7; you want [IOError](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError) and will have to print out the number or message to determine what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to split on the `=` character in a style that seems to be [standard INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), it is safe to assume that your pairs will be at max size 2. I'm not a fan of using methods that rely on character checking (unless specifically called for), so give this a whirl:

```
def search(param):
    result = '0' # declare here
    try:
        with open('config.txt') as configuration:
            for line in configuration:
                if not line:
                    continue  

                f_pair = line.strip().split("=") # remove \r\n, \n

                if len(f_pair) > 2: # your separator will be much longer
                    continue
                else if f_pair[0] == param:
                    result = f_pair[1]
                    # result = f_input.split() # why the 'split()' here?
                    break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found: ")

    return result

mqttIsAllowed=search("Mqtt_allowed")
```

I'm pretty sure the error you were getting was a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Here is how I know that:

When you call this function for any of the `Mqtt_*` values, the loop **never** encounters the separator string `<=============>`. As soo as you try to call anything below that first separator (for example a `cloud_*` key), the loop eventually reaches the first separator and tries to execute:

`function, f_input = line.split('=')`

But that wont work, in fact it will tell you:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

And that is because you are forcing the `split()` call to push into only 2 variables, but a `split('=')` on your separator string will return a list of 15 elements (a `'<'`, a `'>'` and 13 `''`). Thus, doing what I have posted above ensures that your `split('=')` still goes off, but checks to see if you hit a separator or not.

Comment: `line.split("=").strip()` doesn't work because `str.split` returns a list, which doesn't have the `strip` method.

Comment: ok thanks pstatix, but how to get separate values, now i am getting all the text file in line, i want to have function and f_input separately..

Comment: @HassanHaroon Sorry, missed that part as well. Still a bit groggy...need more coffee. Please see my update for list indexing.

Comment: @HassanHaroon What do you mean you are getting all of the text file in line?

Comment: i mean only line is defined for the split and strip function, no function and f_input

Comment: @HassanHaroon The updates should cover entirely. If the line can be `split('=')` we store it in `f_pair`; if it is a valid line, it will only have 2 elements, otherwise its an invalid line and we move on. If its valid, we get `function` at index `0` and `f_input` at index `1`.

Comment: i just changed the separator to <!!!!!!!=!!!!!!!!>.. and i think its ok now, not much complex....

Answer (score 1):

Just skip all the lines starting with `<`:

```
if not line or line.lstrip().startswith("<"):
    continue
```

Or, if you really, really want to match the separator exactly:

```
if line.strip() == "<=============>":
    continue
```

I think the first variant is better because if someone slightly modified the separator by accident, the second piece of code won't work at all.

Comment: Personally I think it is better to explain to the OP what they did wrong (even though they didn't post the error) since they have a misunderstanding of the unpacking syntax.

Comment: @pstatix, ...or they just forgot that `line.split("=")` would also affect the separator, which happens to consist of `=`s.

Comment: Even still, what if the user wanted to change the separator start character? Or make a key that starts with `'<'` such as `'<usr_grp>'`. Better to go with standard file formatting that char sequencing.

Comment: @pstatix, what if they wanted to change "something"? They'd probably have to modify their code to correctly process the change anyway since the code is designed to process this specific format, and the format has been created to be parsed by this exact code. Unless they're trying to implement the INI format, but this looks like overkill right now.